# Excel Vba Macro Error 400 For Emailing Current Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

New-ish to creating macros for excel and cannot get any clarity on why the code I have written is giving an Error 400.

```
Sub Send_Email()

    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object

    If Range(A1).Value = 22 / 9 / 2019 Then   'cell A1 has =TODAY() method

        If Range(C15).Value = 1 Then   'cell C15 has conditional formatting

            Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)

            With outlookMail
                .To = "example@email.com"
                .Subject = "Weekly Timetable"
                .BodyFormat = 2
                .HTMLBody = "<p>This is your schedule for the week</p><p>Thanks,</p><p>Aaron</p>"
                .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
                .Importance = 1
                .Send
            End With

            Set Range(C15).Value = 3   'changes value to 3 to change condition

        End If

    End If

    Set outlookMail = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Expected result is that if the date in A1 is 22/09/2019 and C15 contains value 1 that the email will be formed and sent to the email(changed for purpose of this question) of the ".To" property and then the value in C15 to be changed to prevent duplicate emails. If any can help it will be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Change `22 / 9 / 2019` to `CDate("22/9/2019")` - your code is just diving 22 by 9 by 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your ranges in quotations `("A1")`and `("C15")` as well as make your `22 / 9 / 2019` to  `"22/9/2019"`.

Also, you don't want to `set Range("C15").value` just change the value.

```
Sub Send_Email()

    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)

        If Range("A1").Value = "22/9/2019" And Range("C15").Value = 1 Then

            With outlookMail
                .To = "example@email.com"
                .Subject = "Weekly Timetable"
                .BodyFormat = 2
                .HTMLBody = "<p>This is your schedule for the week</p><p>Thanks,</p><p>Aaron</p>"
                .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
                .Importance = 1
                .Send
            End With

            Range("C15").Value = 3   'changes value to 3 to change condition

        End If

    Set outlookMail = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```